# Create qrCode with output base64 from javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, qr-code

I want to create qr-code with output base64 string from javascript.

I found http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ for generate qr-code.
That I want is get base64 string from this awesome tools.

Comment: it's already Base64, just get the URL from the generated image.

Answer (score 4):

Install the library qrcode https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode

Instalation command: **npm i qrcode**

Then use the next code:

```
    const QRCode = require('qrcode');

    let QRbase64 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        QRCode.toDataURL('I love tacos!!', function (err, code) {
            if (err) {
                reject(reject);
                return;
            }
            resolve(code);
        });
    });
    
    console.log(QRbase64);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the Base64 directly from the generated variable, i.e.:

```
/*generate QRCode*/
var qrcodjs = new QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: orderData.reference,
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark: "#000000",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});

/*get base64*/
var imgBase64Data = qrcodjs._el.childNodes[4].currentSrc;
```

This will work unfortunately only on google chrome or Firefox... for IE or Safari you will have to use:

```
                var imgBase64 = qrcodjs._oDrawing._elImage.currentSrc;
                if (typeof imgBase64 === "undefined")
                    imgBase64 = qrcodjs._oDrawing._elImage.href;
                if (typeof imgBase64 === "undefined")
                    imgBase64 = qrcodjs._oDrawing._elImage.src;
```

Answer (score 2):

just use below given  any one of the qr  js library to get base64

1.qrcodejs

2.easyqrcodejs

```
var qrcodjs = new QRCode("qrcode", {
    text: orderData.reference,
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    colorDark: "#000000",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
});
```

base64

```
qrcode._oDrawing._elCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, any chance of a quick jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can get this code [d-project.googlecode.com](http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/qrcode.js)

And replace last strings

from

```
    var img = '';
    img += '<img';
    img += '\u0020src="';
    img += 'data:image/gif;base64,';
    img += base64;
    img += '"';
    img += '\u0020width="';
    img += width;
    img += '"';
    img += '\u0020height="';
    img += height;
    img += '"';
    if (alt) {
        img += '\u0020alt="';
        img += alt;
        img += '"';
    }
    img += '/>';
```

to

```
    var img = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + base64;
```

Getting a base64

```
    var qr = qrcode(4, 'M');
    qr.addData('This is base64 string');
    qr.make();
    concole.log(qr.createImgTag());
```